# can't install winsound in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

how to install winsound library on Google Colab? I use python 3 and I tried:

```
!pip install winsound
!pip3 install inwound
```

but neither worked, saying

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement winsound (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for winsound

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me hands down on Colab.

```
from IPython.display import Audio
sound_file = 'https://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-01a.mp3'
Audio(sound_file, autoplay=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Winsound is a Windows library, but Google Colaboratory runs off Linux:

```
!uname -a
Linux ea6a927e21de 4.14.33+ #1 SMP Wed Jun 20 01:15:52 PDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thus it is not possible to use Winsound in Google Colaboratory.

Comment: oh thank you! so how can I have a colab cell beep when it's finished? like winsound.Beep()